# Set result format of Facebook Graph API to XML instead of JSON

Tags: xml, json, facebook, graph, format

I'm trying to change the format of the result i get from the facebook graph api to XML.

I use the format=xml parameter but that don't seem to work for me.

https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml

The result is shown in Json format :(

Is it still posible to use the xml format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new graph api always returns data in json.

XML has an overhead on communication size and processing required for parsing so it's being dropped from web API's.

Comment: Pfew, I just wrote a whole class to create an IEnumerable list with user objects from an XML file. (FQL is still returning XML) 
Do you know a good way to show almost all information for multiple users in a gridview? Using Json now? Some code samples anywhere?

Comment: Json is really easy to use. Take a look at the actual API from facebook and read a bit about it on the internet. If you still have issues create a new ticket with your code and actual problems :)

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the old api. Graph api will return JSON objects (which, in my opinion, are much better suited for the job anyway). Verbatim from the facebook graph API documentation:

> All responses are JSON objects.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook to XML. Firstly reference Newtonsoft.Json.net

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

for example...

```
var facebookJson = fb.Get("/me");
```

then...

```
XmlNode facebookUserObjxml = (XmlNode)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"root\":" + facebookJson.ToString() + "}", "root");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$fbInfoUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$token;<br/>
$fbInfo = file_get_contents($fbInfoUrl);<br/>
$fbInfoObj = json_decode($fbInfo, true);<br/>
```

You'll get an Object in XML format in `$fbInfoObj`.

Comment: This returns a PHP array, not XML. You would need to use: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();`