# Extract insights using Oracle/SQL http requests

Tags: sql, facebook

I'm trying to extract the Facebook insights data using Oracle http requests through the API. I'm trying to connect to Facebook via the API using Oracle http request command and then insert the insights data to a table in my Oracle database.  In Oracle I can 'read' (select) XML formatted data and then insert it to a database table. . Is that possible using the API?
Thanks,
Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the insights are returned in JSON format.  It is not possible to change it to return in XML format (per [Set result format of Facebook Graph API to XML instead of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540322/set-result-format-of-facebook-graph-api-to-xml-instead-of-json))

Maybe Oracle has some utility to convert JSON to XML?